# Is there any way to insert into int(11) type mysql table double numbers?

Tags: mysql

Hello I have MySQL table called **building_type_id** and in there I want to insert 2 numbers example 40 and 18 at the moment there is 1 number 18, is there any way to insert double numbers? that table is int(11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to link the table to multiple building types, you need a join table.

For example, I'm assuming you currently have something like:

```
BUILDING
id
building_type_id
address

BUILDING TYPE
id
title
```

You need to link the two via a link table, like this:

```
BUILDING
id
address

BUILDING - BUILDING TYPE
building_id
building_type_id

BUILDING TYPE
id
title
```

You can then add two rows to the building to building type join table:

```
building_id    building_type_id
1              18
1              40
```